# How to remotely clone Git repository on Windows Storage Server 2008?

Tags: git, repository

I have a Western Digital Sentinel at home running Windows Storage Server 2008 R2 Essentials. I have several Git repositories on it for my own personal projects, and have no problems pushing and pulling over my local network. I want to be able to access those repositories remotely from anywhere. I am able to log in and remotely access folders and files in the repositories, but I cannot clone them using the same address. It hangs for a really long time before finally failing with this error:

```
git.exe clone   --progress -v  "https://myIpAddressHere/Remote/fs/files.aspx?path=%5C%5Cmydevicename%5Cmyreposfolder%5Cmyrepo.git" "D:\repo"

Cloning into 'D:\repo'...
error: Failed connect to myIpAddress:443; No error while accessing https://myIpAddress/Remote/fs/files.aspx?path=%5C%5Cmydevicename%5Cmyreposfolder%5Cmyrepo.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

I'm not too knowledgeable about networking or web development, and I have only a rudimentary understanding of how to use Git (with TortoiseGit). I'm having a hard time finding search results for this specific problem and a hard time interpreting generic tutorials for the general scope of this problem. What troubleshooting steps can I do to find and resolve the problem?

I'm using TortoiseGit 1.7.13.0 with Git version 1.7.10.mysysgit.1.